# Elasticsearch aggregation on latest N records

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

Is there any way to do aggregation on latest N records?

this solution didn't work

```
{
   "query": {...},
   "size": N,
   "order": ...,
   "aggs": {
       ....
   }
}
```

for more detail: I want to get last 10 records from my records where "service_name" field is "x" and then aggregate on these 10 records to find out how many of these records have "success" in "resp_code" field.

my data is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1232525",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resp_body": "",
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "resp_time": "2021-04-15T10:24:51+01:00",
      "@timestamp": "2021-04-15T05:55:00.452Z",
      "resp_code": "412",
      "service_name": "service1",
      "log_id": "1232525"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1232524",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resp_body": "",
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "resp_time": "2021-04-15T10:23:51+01:00",
      "@timestamp": "2021-04-15T05:53:00.452Z",
      "resp_code": "0",
      "service_name": "service2",
      "log_id": "1232524"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1232523",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resp_body": "",
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "resp_time": "2021-04-15T10:22:51+01:00",
      "@timestamp": "2021-04-15T05:52:00.452Z",
      "resp_code": "0",
      "service_name": "service1",
      "log_id": "1232523"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1232522",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resp_body": "",
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "resp_time": "2021-04-15T10:21:51+01:00",
      "@timestamp": "2021-04-15T05:51:00.452Z",
      "resp_code": "0",
      "service_name": "service1",
      "log_id": "1232522"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1232521",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resp_body": "",
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "resp_time": "2021-04-15T10:20:51+01:00",
      "@timestamp": "2021-04-15T05:50:00.452Z",
      "resp_code": "0",
      "service_name": "service2",
      "log_id": "1232521"
    }
  }
]
```

for example: I want to get last 2 records with "service_name=service1" and find how many records of those have "resp_code=0"

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: you want to get last 10 records on the basis of timestamp ? Do you have any field in your data on the basis of which you want to retrieve latest N records ?

Comment: I want last 10 records based on ID or a field time

Comment: its difficult to assume the field values, can you please share some sample index data ?

Comment: @ESCoder I edited the question with sample data

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), and [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to achieve your required result.

1. Using filter aggregation (`first_filter`), first, those documents are filtered having `"service_name=service1"`
2. Then terms aggregation is used (`top_terms_aggregation`) to create buckets of the filtered document based on the `log_id` field. These buckets are sorted in `desc` order based on the `@timestamp` field (using max aggregation)
3. Again using filter aggregation (`second_filter`), those documents are filtered out having `"resp_code=0"`

---

Adding a working example with index mapping, data (same as that of question), search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "first_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "service_name.keyword": "service1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_terms_aggregation": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "log_id.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "second_filter>latestRecord": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "second_filter": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "resp_code": "0"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "latestRecord": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "@timestamp"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "first_filter": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "top_terms_aggregation": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "1232523",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "second_filter": {
              "doc_count": 1,
              "latestOrder": {
                "value": 1.618465920452E12,
                "value_as_string": "2021-04-15T05:52:00.452Z"      // note this
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "1232522",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "second_filter": {
              "doc_count": 1,
              "latestOrder": {
                "value": 1.618465860452E12,
                "value_as_string": "2021-04-15T05:51:00.452Z"          // note this
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "1232525",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "second_filter": {
              "doc_count": 0,
              "latestOrder": {
                "value": null
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Behzad Dadashpour please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?